# iOS: call mobile phone screen with phone number like on Android

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to make same action like on Android, when we press Phone icon in application?

On Android we will see Phone Call screen with entered phone number.
On iOS it will call to a phone number immediately.

**Example:**
**Android:** Some app call button click -> Native Android Phone Call screen with pre-entered number -> Manual click call button
**iOS:** Same app call button click -> Immediately call action to phone number
I need to know, is it possible to add 2nd step into iOS like on Android.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible by using openUrl as follows, i wrote in swift u can try same in objc

// swift

```
 func makePhoneCall(_ phoneNumber: String?) {
    if phoneNumber != nil && phoneNumber?.length ?? 0 > 0 {
        let charSet: CharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789-+()").inverted
        let cleanedString: String? = (phoneNumber!.components(separatedBy: charSet) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by:"")
        let escapedPhoneNumber: NSString? = cleanedString?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) as NSString?
        let phoneURLString: String = String(format:"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber!)
        let phoneURL: URL? = URL(string: phoneURLString)
        if phoneURL != nil {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(phoneURL!) == true {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(phoneURL!)
            } else {
                // show alert or something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// objc

```
-(void) makePhoneCall:(NSString *)phoneNumber {
if(phoneNumber.length > 0) {
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789-+()"] invertedSet];
    NSString *cleanedString = [[phoneNumber componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *escapedPhoneNumber = [cleanedString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:  [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *phoneURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@", escapedPhoneNumber];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneURLString];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    } else {
        // show alert // or something
    }

}
}
```

Comment: this method will call immediately to phone number without intermediate screen like on Android

Comment: Just be aware that the `telprompt:` scheme is not documented and therefor not future prove since Apple can choose to remove it at any moment.

Comment: if you want to do like android , you need design one screen before calling the make call function

Comment: i've checked both tel:// and telprompt:// on iPhone and both works equally with simple alert dialog